# libgdx actor bounds and events

Tags: java, libgdx

Using box2d, I have a static ground in the bottom of the screen and a box falling from above. Trying actor events, the ground fires the event but the falling box doesn't.

Actor creation: (The static ground fills the width of the screen and 20px tall from the bottom.I tried to use setPosition but the result was wrong.)

```
box = new MyActor(world);
box.setOrigin(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, 200);
box.makeBody(20, 20, true); //defines body and fixture
stage.addActor(a);
```

I guess the issue is in the actor's bounds. I set it like this:

```
setHeight(h); //the w and h are arguments from makeBody() method.
setWidth(w);
setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You do set the position to 0,0 in your `setBounds`. So the event would be somewhere in the left up corner. The first values of the Setbounds is the postion of your "body". So set the right width and correct Position with the `setBounds` and it should work fine.

Comment: I know I have to set the bounds correctly. That's what I said, the issue is in the bounds. I'm asking for suggestions on how to do is right.

I set the bounds in the creation of the actor, so should I update it relative to the actor's position every frame?

Comment: yes you should. Else the picture is at an different position from the actor. You usually update the actors position. (`.setPosition(x,y)`) and draw the picutre or whatever of it depending on the `getX()` and `getY()`.